# How to Define ValidateAntiForgeryToken in web.config?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

Now I'm using `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` foreach post action when needed. I would like to define this in the config file as it is the case of `[ValidateInput]`.

How to do it? I don't want to use `Filter` as suggested somewhere by a stackoverer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain about this, but I don't think it can be set up in web.config. You need an attribute on each POST Action method that employs the token.